# How do I set a variable equal to a value running FB.api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example:

```
var temp = FB.api('/me', function(response) { });}
```

I basically want the array of response to be assigned to temp so I can access any of the information at will

Answer (score 0):

The API is asynchronous so you need to run the code depending on the value returned by it in the callback function.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? Do you mean I won't be able to extract anything out of this? I have to do whatever I want within the function?

Comment: Yes, inside `function(response) { }` - but you can call another function in there of course.

Comment: Got it. Facebook migrated to OAuth 2.0 and having to fix a lot of things!

Comment: I'm new here but any chance I could catch you on IM/Email to look at an error?

Comment: nope. but there are enough programming irc channels where you could ask people

Comment: No worries, thanks though! Is there one you recommend specifically Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API functions need to get data from the facebook servers. So you need to tell the FB.api() function what to do with the data **once** you get it.

Actually, you already have your data somewhere : the *response* parameter of the anonymous function passed to FB.api ;) That function will be launched **once** the data we're speaking of will be available and that data will be contained in that *response* parameter

Try that :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) { console.log(response); });}
```

You should see the data returned by the API in your development console after a short time.

Comment: That is what I did and it works well. But instead of console.log(response); if I do something like var temp = response; I am unable to use the variable "temp" outside of the FB.api function. I'm assuming the variable only becomes contained within the function?

Comment: Exactly. This behavior is because of a thing called "Scope". When you declare a variable in a function (or use a parameter of that function), that variable will only be available in the function.
But in our case it's not a problem at all, you just have to put your code in that function. That code will run **once** you have your data (which is what you want ;) )

Comment: Thanks Hezad. I appreciate your help. With the change in FB Java SDK. I've been trying to fix this stuff all day!

Comment: Any chance I can catch you on IM to look at something for me?

Comment: Java**script** SDK to be pedantic ;) Anyway, good luck with the API !